# Clickable tooltip using qTips2 targeting title attribute. jQuery tooltip problems

Tags: jquery, tooltip, qtip

I can not get a tooltip working using qTips2: - 
http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/demos/#tips

I need to have an image next to a label, which when clicked on opens up a tooltip. The tooltip will be using the title, eg title="tooltip here" but only within a certain div #toolTipArea.

Once the tooltip is opened it will have a close button like on the demo link above.

Hope someone can help me get a tooltip like the above link.

Cheers